# When using JavaScript's reduce, how do I skip an iteration?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out a way to conditionally break out of an iteration when using JavaScript's `reduce` function.

Given the following code sums an array of integers and will return the number `10`:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

How can I do something like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  if(currentValue === "WHATEVER") {
    // SKIP or NEXT -- don't include it in the sum
  }
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

Comment: Consider also filtering out the WHATEVER values before calling `reduce`.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can just return previousValue

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  if(currentValue === "WHATEVER") {
    return previousValue;
  }
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

Comment: Just a note that where this says `previousValue` while that's correct, some might find it easier to remember it's the accumulator, and that is what you should indeed return.

Comment: yeah @SebastianThomas - I tend to agree, today - but in the context of this question it is more descriptive ... at least, that's what I thought **FOUR** years ago

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a ternary operator to pass the previous value if the condition is `true` ..or perform a certain action if `false`

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array)=>  {
  return(condition)?  previousValue : previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

Comment: While this is correct, it's a syntax that's not very readable.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to place an if statement, do your reducing logic there ignore other conditions.
For example:

Instead of doing this:

```
let a = sorted.reduce((item,total)=>{
    if(total+item > k) return total;
ans++;
return total + item;
})
```

This works perfectly:

```
    let a = sorted.reduce((item,total)=>{
    if(total+item <= k) {
            ans++;
            return total + item;
    }
})
```